# Query model with belongs_to via params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have this query in my controller that takes parameters as arguments

```
@animal = Animal.where(animal_type: params[:animal_type], rehomed: params[:rehomed])
```

What i would like to do though is query a column from another model

```
class Animal
 belongs_to :user
end
```

Am i right in thinking i can use .includes ?

```
@animal = Animal.includes(:user).where('users.town = ?', "#{params[:animal_town]}")
```

Im getting syntax errors and am a bit lost on how to construct this query, ideally i would like to query the user table for towns and also the animal table for animal_type and rehomed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you should actually use [`joins`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-joins):

```
@animal = Animal.joins(:user).where(users: { town: params[:animal_town] })
```

BTW, `"#{params[:animal_town]}"` makes no sense since it's equivalent to `params[:animal_town]`.

Comment: how would i pass in the rest of the params for my animal model ? can i just chain them ?

Comment: @Richlewis it depends on what params you have and what query you need to perform.

Comment: so doing this would not work, or should i say doing this is not the way to do it `Animal.where(animal_type: params[:animal_type], rehomed: params[:rehomed]).joins(:user).where(users: {town: params[:animal_town]})`

Comment: actually that works but is it the most efficient way of doing it ?

Comment: It is the most efficient way. Eventually, it can be refactored to:
`Animal.joins(:user).where(animal_type: params[:animal_type], rehomed: params[:rehomed], users: {town: params[:animal_town]})` to make it a little bit clearer.